How to correctly typeset/format your LaTeX documents?
I came across this short article providing a brief introduction on how to typeset documents in LaTeX. It's from 2013, however, and LaTeX has developed since then. Thus, I was wondering if we could gather all of the up-to-date advice or tips/tricks for how to correctly typeset your documents on this site.
Answers could be anything from how you should start a new paragraph to how you should write math (display mode and in-line mode, for example). How should you write footnotes, lists, table of contents, bibliography, figures, how to handle floats etc. Additionally, it'd be a nice bonus if you could also mention what you shouldn't do with these problems (are there some environments/packages/commands you should generally avoid using for solving the task, for example). Packages may also be recommended for improved typesetting (for example the zref-clever package makes referencing easier and more consistent). The geometry package is good for adjusting the margins of your document. How should this be done, and what values are ideal/best supported for the margins in your document? You can also elaborate/update upon some of the points mentioned in the article if it merely needs some revision, or search inspiration from there on what else to cover.
I hope this gives an idea of how extensive I hope the coverage of the LaTeX basics will be in this post. Every small detail matters when it comes to typesetting documents, so don't hold back on anything - Your contribution is appreciated, no matter how small!

The LaTeX routines that run in the background may have changed since the article you cite was first published. However, LaTeX' overarching design philosophy that should be reflected in a decent LaTeX document has not changed significantly over this period.

But I still couldn't find any questions in here that addresses general typesetting etiquettes, and the article certainly doesn't cover all the areas, either. I deliberately listed a few examples beyond the article so that we may point out new/lesser known details as well as reaffirm "the big basics" mentioned in the article, if they still hold true. Reassurance doesn't hurt, and having multiple sources point towards the same approach further reinforces that particular statement and increases availability of the information (Don't have to dig as deep, perhaps)

The question as stated meets the standard close reasons for being too broad, and the answer posted suggests you should have a question more like "how do you mark paragraphs with vertical space rather than indent"

I recommend starting with the O.G. documentation, Leslie Lamport's "LaTeX: A Document Preparation System" (2nd Edition). Then there's a couple of good web sites: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/, and this reference manual https://latexref.xyz. There's more where these came from, but absorb them and you'll have a good start.

To learn the basics read learnlatex.org. I'd start there if I had to start from zero now.

I'd like to mention that it's absolutely essential that you start a new paragraph by ending the current one with a blank line or use \par, both of which refer to the same in LaTeX. Never use ... old paragraph. \\ \\ New paragraph... as it may visually look like a new paragraph, because it's functionally just empty lines of text in the first paragraph and is interpreted as such in LaTeX. This may therefore cause some weird interactions with other packages since they depend on correct distinction between a new paragraph and a new line within a paragraph. An example of this can be seen in my problem where it was solved using the correct syntax.
You may not like how a new paragraph is indicated on LaTeX by default since it just starts a new line with an indent:

This can be fixed by setting the paragraph indent to zero in the preamble using \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}, however. You can also adjust the vertical spacing between paragraphs. This can be done using \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip} in the preamble. Together, these 2 settings change the paragraph layout to the following:

Here's the code for it:
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating random text

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Adjusting paragraph indent

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip} % Adjusting paragraph spacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % First paragraph

\lipsum[2] % Second paragraph

\end{document}

Alternatively, you could also use the parskip package instead as it loads those settings by default.

You wrote, "it's absolutely essential that you start a new paragraph by ending the current one with a blank line or use \par." That piece of advice was as true in 2013 as it's now.

Off-topic: the lipsum package does not produce random text. If you execute \lipsum[1] a dozen times, it'll produce the exact same text each and every time.

Yes, and thus I reaffirmed the approach mentioned in the article and wrote it in a (hopefully) easier way to understand with dedicated examples. When it comes to in line math mode, however, it's different. The new notation is \( \) yet I see many people still using $ $ for example. Thus, you should expect this post to contain new as well as old information. I can also tell you as a newcomer to LaTeX myself that just because something has been out for a while doesn't mean it has necessarily been addressed

You're right with regards to  the lipsum package. My apologies for incorrectly articulating myself. Do you reckon I should update it to "For generating fixed, random text"?

How aboit a one time pad?  (Actually, even cryptography quality pseudo-random number generatores don't generate random numbers.)

There's nothing new about using \( and \) to initiate and terminate inline math mode. It's been around since the very earliest days of LaTeX as a format. Please see the following posting, from way back in 2010, Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode? and the associated answers for a related discussion.

This can be fixed by setting the paragraph indent to zero in the preamble using \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}, however. You can also adjust the vertical spacing between paragraphs. This can be done using \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}  this is bad advice. If you just set parindent to 0 there is no clear paragraph mark and if you set \parskip to a fixed non stretchy length that is not a multiple of \baselineskip  pages with just text can not fit in the \textheight

parskip package instead as it loads those settings by default.  No. it uses stretchy space

"This can be fixed" nothing is broken. "This can be changed" would be correct.

The comment about \\  seems completely out of place. The question claims to be asking about good typographic style, but the \\  sentence in this answer  is just basic latex syntax. and the rest of the answer is answering an unrelated question about how to mark paragraphs with vertical space.
